# Blade Echoing Extra Spaces

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Sorry for my poor english. I'm getting a lot of unwanted whitespaces in  html because blade echoes.

```
<td>
    {{ $user->name }}
</td>
<td>
    {{ $user->email }}
</td>
```

Expected:

```
<td>User</td>
<td>user@example.com</td>
```

Results:

```
<td>
                                                                        User
                                                                    </td>
<td>
                                                                        user@example.com
                                                                    </td>
```

Comment: is it on your browser?

Comment: Laravel itself cannot minify the output. You need an additional package for that or code it yourself (e.g. as middleware).

Comment: try `{{ trim($user->name) }}`

Comment: Try `<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>` without any whitespace or newline.